# Recommended component to use in aws to connect to on-premise services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried to search relevant info but couldn't find anything relevant. Please point me to some links on this.
I would like to know what is the best way to:

Connect to on-premise SOAP services from AWS cloud
on-premise Java RMI services
on-premise FTP to exchange files
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to SOAP, Java RMI or FTP service on-premise is something that will part of your application logic implementation. Which infrastructure you choose to deploy your application is a matter of choice depending on factors like what knowledge you have, what other application requirements you have and so on. Provided that you have configured your on-premise servers so that they are available on the public internet, you can choose to deploy your application using any server hosting option. For AWS specifically, EC2, Elastic Beanstalk and container options EKS and ECS comes to mind in addition to Lambda.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Elastic Beanstalk servers and wanted to know if there are any standard products to communicate with on-premise servers like API Gateway (I am not sure if this is a correct component). That's what I want to know. I am not worried about how i am hosting app on cloud.... it's more about how we communicate to these on premise services....i thought there would be a standard way at least for SOAP requests.